# Search richtextbox for string match and then record the index in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, search, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox that has been filled with data on each lines. I want to read each line and find the matching word in the list and records it's index value, then exit the loop.

Then at some point in the program, I want to read the same richtextbox and copy the line data of the matching index that I obtained before.

So far I have managed to do the following:

```
For Each item As String In rtb_critical.Lines

 If item.Contains("Failed to initialise") = True Then
            MsgBox("yes")
Else
 MsgBox("no")
End if
Next
```

I Also found this code, but don't know how I can use this to get what I want.

```
Dim index As Integer = 0

 Do
    ' Find occurrences of the search word, incrementing  
    ' the start index. 
    index = RichTextBox1.Find(searchWord, index + 1, _
        RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase)
    If (index <> -1) Then

      lineList.Add(RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index))
    End If
Loop While (index <> -1)
```

Could anyone please assist me?

Thank You

Comment: Do you really need a RichTextBox? If just plain text I suggest you use a TextBox with Multiline turned on - you'll avoid a lot of problems.

Comment: you mentioned I will avoid problems, what kind for my case?

Comment: As long as you are very careful that only text goes into the RTB you will probably be OK. If the user can paste you may wind up with RTF codes in the text if the program that copied the text knows about RTF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a for loop from 0 to the Lines.Count -1 of the RTB. This iterator variable would then be the index position.

So when a line is found your iterator variable is the index to store

```
for i as integer = 0 to rtb1.lines.count-1
   if rtb1.lines(i).Contains("a search string")
     'store i as that holds the index of the line found
   end if
next
```

Comment: That works to get the index, but If I want to later read the line with this index value and copy it to another richtextbox, how do I do that?  I tried rtb2.Lines = rtb1.Lines(index), but it gives an error.

Comment: figured it out, it needs to be rtb2.text